# Rails 3 Devise: Change e-mail recipient

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I'm using Devise to confirm user e-mails but instead of sending the confirmation e-mail to the user, I'd like to send to an admin and other e-mail to the user.

IF and when the admin confirms the user e-mail, a welcome e-mail is sent to the user.

How can I change the recipient and the content of the confirmation e-mail?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Most straight forward approach would be not to use Devise's  Confirmable but write your own instead. Checkout the `lib/devise/models/confirmable.rb` file, copy what you need and add what is missing.

Comment: I do not have a devise folder inside the lib/.

Comment: That's the folder structure of the devise gem. Either browse devise on github or grab the gemedit gem via `gem install gemedit` (see http://gemedit.rubyforge.org/ ) and `gem edit -e mate devise` to view the devise source in TextMate.